# White spaces in ansible task module

Tags: python, ansible, yaml

I need some assistance accounting for the white space between `valid users` and `create mask` without having to join them with an underscore. These are standard samba configuration options with spaces between them. I tried doing including a `\t` but that didn't work.

Below is the ansible task i currently have setup which is throwing errors because of the space.

```
name: smb.conf
ini_file: 
  dest: /etc/samba/smb.conf 
  mode: 0644 
  section: {{ item.section }} 
  path: {{ item.path }} 
  public: {{ item.public }} 
  valid users: {{ item.valid users}} 
  create mask: {{ item.create mask }}
with_items:
- { section: 'samba', path: '/home/user', public: 'no' , valid users: @admin create mask: '0775' }
```

Comment: Please add part of `smb.conf` you try to create with this task. But you definitely try to use `ini_file` in wrong way. You should use `option` and `value` parameters.

Comment: There is no whitespace between `valid users` and `create mask` in your sample as there is `@admin` there. Please update your post so it is clear what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Anthon.So u dont see a difference between `validusers`  and  `valid users` ? I also indicated i don't want to join the words with an underscore like so `valid_user`. I can never understand people who come on stackoverflow only to make stupid comments without adding any value?

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
{{ item["valid users"] }}
```